# How to use E1 as E0?

Tags: marlin, firmware, motor

Like many people, I have burnt the pins in the micro-controller connected to the E0 motor - the E0 motor is not working anymore and I need to print tomorrow! I need to control the extruder motor with the working E1 pins. How do I change this in firmware?

I tried to change to the pins in `pins_RAMPS.h" but it was a complete fail, the motors that i tried to change didn't move.

I have a Arduino Mega + Ramps 1.3 in "Extruder Fan Bed" configuration, I use Repetier-Host as host and Marlin as firmware.

Comment: How did you find that Arduino pins were burnt? Have you tried spare motor driver?

Comment: @MikhailZ Yes definitely ! I swapt the drivers to test them, and I always replace the bad drivers with new/repaired ones.

Comment: Changing pins_RAMPS should work. You must have done something wrong when trying it.

Comment: To elaborate on [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/3183/5740) of Thomas S, a more detailed description of swapping the pins is found in [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/5844/5740) 3D.SE answer. Please vote and accept an answer (we want this community to get out of Beta stage), thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I would change the pin assignments by swapping E0 and E1 in `pins_RAMPS.h`.

Comment: A more detailed answer is found [here](/a/5844).

Answer (score 4):

As a quick and dirty solution you may try to enable two extruders in configuration file, re-upload firmware, and then edit your GCODE file to replace all E0 references with E1.

Comment: That's a really good idea. It should be possible to have the firmware do it. Or there must be a script that can be ran... But it doesn't seem this firmware is all that great. I would suggest a different firmware if it doesn't do what is needed.