# How to upload firmware to reprap printer?

Tags: firmware

When trying to upload firmware I get the following errors:

1. `timeout - cannot sync`, or
2. `port is in use`

What can be the possible sources of these errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are mainly three reasons for that:

1. Arduino studio settings should be:

   - Board: Mega 2560 and
   - Programmer: AVR ISP
   - **and valid COM port**, please see below:

[image: Arduino settings]

2. Please close all slicer's instances (Cura, Slic3r, Repetiter)  and host servers and other software that communicate with the printer as they lock the COM port;
3. Please check that the appropriate usb2serial drivers are installed and working - the best way is to start the serial monitor from the Arduino Studio Tools menu and see if there are any.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the slicer software in the overview, the slicer is frequently overlooked and certainly got me  a few times wondering why it would not upload!

Comment: how about a too-high baud rate?

Comment: @Roger the baud rate is determined by board/programmer in Arduino Studio, that means we don't have access to set it.

Comment: 4. There is a preloaded task in your Arduino, I´ve seen this several times.